# Call WebServices from JavaScript without using ScriptManager in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have created a Web service for my Asp.net project. At present I'm accessing the service from JavaScript by referencing the Service in `ScriptManager`. But I don't want to add a `ScriptManager` so that I can use it in  any HTML page.

Comment: so you want to call your webservice using JavaScript ajax not by using ScriptManager ??

Comment: Ya Exactly!!! Also need to pass parameters

Comment: You can always write your own Javascript and/or use a library (e.g. Jquery) if you want and build your own Ajax requests and parse responses.

Comment: I found something , but it doesn't say how to pass parameters. My method requires two string inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. so you want to make ajax call to some web-service method and pass parameters to it. And you are going to pass the parameters as JSON format

```
function CallWebServiceMethod() {
     var requestedData = "{ 'LifeCycleN': '" + var_LifeCycleN +//var_LifeCycleN some var represent your data that you want to send
            "', 'LiOrder': '" + var_LiOrder +//var_LiOrder again some var represent your data that you want to send
            "'}";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Services/YouWebServiceName.asmx/WebServiceMethodName",
        data: requestedData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {// I 'll assume that your web-service 'll return bool value indicate if the operation done successfully or not.
        //do here what you want to do is the request was successful.
        }
    });

    }
```

Comment: Ya this is what I Exactly wanted. Let me try it! Thank You

Comment: if you want me to explain more just tell me.

Comment: `[WebMethod]
    public static void GetStageList(string LifeCycleN, string LiOrder)`

Comment: This is how my webservice accepts values. then how should i  `var requestedData'must be

Comment: i updated the code..please tell me which part is not working or what's the error you get?

Comment: @SubinJacob yes. If no data to send then remove it.

Comment: But nothing Happens.I added an alert message

Comment: POST http://localhost:1564/WebServiceCall/~/WebServices/MySampleService.asmx/GetServerResponse 500 (Internal Server Error) ... This Is the error that chrome shows in its javascript console

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26033/discussion-between-subin-jacob-and-ebram-tharwat)

Comment: yes (Internal Server Error) because of what?? open the request response or preview and read the error.

Comment: The error was because of the url. I corrected it. But now the problem is this. alert(msg); gives object Object

Comment: @ebramkhalil Could you please explain the ajax portion.i am looking for it but couldn't find any help

Comment: @NaredlaNitheshReddy, I'm not sure what you are looking for, but this is a simple jQuery ajax request. The only trick here is to construct the passed data as a JSON manually.